# Linux PyQt5 program to run on windows

Tags: windows, pyqt5

I've made a handy (for me) python program on my linux home computer, that I could really use at work, which are windows 10 computers. Is there a way to make it an exe file I could run at work?
python 3.7
QtPy5
Ubuntu 20.04
work computers are windows 10

Comment: What OS/release are you talking about, the only OS you mention is windows.

Comment: You can use WSL. Please give the edition and version of windows OS